# Opening .txt file and making a new tuple collection

Tags: python

fruit.txt

```
apple 
banana 
mango 
cherry
```

I want to open the `fruit.txt` file in `.py` file, and I want to have tuple collection of fruits. An example is shown below:

```
fruits = ("apple", "banana", "mango", "cherry")
```

I searched for that, and I got I need to use `open(fruit.txt,'r')` to open the .txt file. But how can I make the list?

Comment: You want to make a list? yet `fruits = ("apple", "banana", "mango", "cherry")` is a tuple and not a list. You can use `lines = open(fruit.txt,'r')` and `line.readlines()` will be a list of all the lines in the txt file

Comment: then, how can I use the tuple?

Comment: convert the list to a tuple using `tuple()` ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To help you get the best result on Stack Overflow, see how to ask good questions[https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask]. Make sure your question covers these 3 elements: 1. Problem Statement 2. Your Code (it should be Minimal, Reproducible Example[https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example]) 3. Error Message (preferably full Traceback to help others review and provide feedback).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way out if the fruits are in different lines inside your text file

```
fruits = open('fruits.txt','r') #opening the file
lines = fruits.readlines() #making list, with the line break
fruit = [] #empty list to later append without the line break
for line in lines: #looping through the list
    stripped = line.strip('\n') #removing the linebreak
    fruit.append(stripped) #appending to the new list

main_tup = tuple(fruit) #making it to a tuple 
print(main_tup)
```

Here is a shorter way to write this code using list comprehension.

```
fruits = open('some.txt','r')
lines = fruits.readlines()
fruit = [line.strip('\n') for line in lines] #list comprehension

main_tup = tuple(fruit)
print(main_tup)
```

Comment: I pressed the upvote, but it said "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." Is it okay?

Comment: @SeyP Its fine, ive update with a shorter piece of code too

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code which reads file lines, and converts them to tuple:

**Case 1:** fruits is a multiple lines file

```
fruits_tuple = tuple(open('fruit.txt', 'r').readlines())
```

**Case 2:** fruits is a single line file

**Case 2.1:** fruits is a single line file, with '\n' as new-line character

```
fruits_tuple = tuple(open('fruit.txt', 'r').readline().split(' \\n'))
```

**Case 2.2:** fruits is a single line file, with '\n' as raw string

```
fruits_tuple = tuple(open('fruit.txt', 'r').readline().split(' \n'))
```

Comment: i think you need to remove the linebreaks too?

Comment: Its recommended to update your answer with this code too

Comment: But i dont think this is a proper way, to `strip()` as it is a list object

Comment: You wouldnt have to remove linebreak if each fruits were in the same line, but instead if it was not, then you would right?